# Opening images from the source of an old game

Tags: image

I want to reuse the images from the 1989 Prince of Persia game. The author put the source code and assets online and here are the images:

https://github.com/jmechner/Prince-of-Persia-Apple-II/tree/master/01%20POP%20Source/Images

But how can I view these images? They are in .dun and .pal format.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not general PC help.

Answer (score 2):

On the Readme he explains that for code exploration and understanding, you must refer to http://www.jordanmechner.com/downloads/popsource.pdf

The files are binaries that he himself created. They are not standard compressed formats.